# Includepdf gives one extra blank page at the end

Tags: pdfpages, revtex

I have written a paper using RevTex in two-column format. I have written some supplemental material in another file in one-column format. Now I want to merge the two. I have something like

```
\documentclass[10pt,prl,aps,showpacs,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\begin{document}
%Paper
\onecolumngrid 
\includepdf[pages={{},-}]{Paper_SupMat.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This works perfectly, albeit that an additional, blank page appears at the end of the document. How can I remove this additional page?

Comment: Not certain, but I don't think there's much you can do about this without redefining bits of the class, which you are probably not supposed to do. Your description and code don't match, by the way. Your code says you're using `twocolumn`. Your description says, you're using one column.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but if there are no ways around this via LaTeX, you can always delete the empty page from the final manuscript with some PDF editor, for example.

Comment: @Troy true but I need to upload the .tex file onto the arXiv (electronic arxiv for papers in, mostly, natural sciences) and the file will be generated automatically.

Comment: @cfr My bad, it is exactly the other way around: the main paper is in the two-column format, whereas the supplemental material is in the one-column format.

Comment: can you post the pdf file to be included?

Comment: Please provide compilable code. Even if I provide the included PDF, that code fails to compile with an error.

Comment: Can you use a different class? There seems to be a pretty fundamental incompatibility here: the class and package both want to change the output routine (I *think*) in essentially inconsistent ways.